# How do I create menu in html with 4 tab which will display content on one single page?

Tags: html, tabs, division, menubar

I need to create one single web page with 4 tab. By pressing on a tab the relevant content should display on the **whole** page and that should work for all tabs. I mean, when user press on one tab it will display content which will be linked to that tab and hide another tab's content. How can I do it in HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final solution to my problem:

```
 function show(showEl) {
        var elements = new Array("tahsilatlarIcerik", "faturaTabGraf", "odemeIcerik", "kasaIcerik");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (showEl == elements[i]) {
                document.getElementById(showEl).style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                hide(elements[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function hide(hideEl) {
        if (document.getElementById(hideEl).style.display != "") {
            document.getElementById(hideEl).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Basically, I've created an Array with elements id's inside and manipulate them with 2 function. Functions are called inside of tabs, e.g., `<a id="faturaMenu" onclick="show('faturaTabGraf')">Fatura Analizi</a>`. I hope this will be helpfull to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI has an out of the box solution for this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Granted it's not a pure HTML and CSS solution however I'm not sure you'll be able to do it without some form of scripting

Comment: #Macros, Than you for your respond.

Comment: Macros, Thank you for your respond. The problem is that I do not have to much time to try to make it with jquery. I know how to hide/show html element in javascript. My problem is much more with web design. Since I will put GriedViews and Charts in almost every tab based content, I just have to figure it out how to make it. I've found on the net <table-layout> propertie and if I set it to auto in multiple table tags and play with display properties by changing it to display:none or display:table I thing I can manage it. But if you have any better idea, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The JQuery control is very easy to use, simply create each of your tbas in it's own DIV (any content can go in there) and then call the constructor in a script block on the page

Answer (score 0):

I solwed problem with javascript code. I am posting it and I am wondering if there is another,
less coded way to do it? As far as I researched, I've found that in javascript declaring and asigning  global variables at the same time is not supported, do you know any other simple way to do it?

AND CODE:

```
        function getFatura() {
        var tahsilatId = document.getElementById("tahsilatlarIcerik");
        var faturaTabloId = document.getElementById("faturaTabloIcerik");
        var faturaGrafikId = document.getElementById("faturaGrafikIcerik");
        var odemelerId = document.getElementById("odemeIcerik");
        var kasaId = document.getElementById("kasaIcerik");

        faturaTabloId.style.display = "block";
        faturaGrafikId.style.display = "block";
        tahsilatId.style.display = "none";
        odemelerId.style.display = "none";
        kasaId.style.display = "none";
    }

    function getTahsilatlar() {
        var tahsilatId = document.getElementById("tahsilatlarIcerik");
        var faturaTabloId = document.getElementById("faturaTabloIcerik");
        var faturaGrafikId = document.getElementById("faturaGrafikIcerik");
        var odemelerId = document.getElementById("odemeIcerik");
        var kasaId = document.getElementById("kasaIcerik");

        faturaTabloId.style.display = "none";
        faturaGrafikId.style.display = "none";
        tahsilatId.style.display = "block";
        odemelerId.style.display = "none";
        kasaId.style.display = "none";
    }

    function getOdemeler() {
        var tahsilatId = document.getElementById("tahsilatlarIcerik");
        var faturaTabloId = document.getElementById("faturaTabloIcerik");
        var faturaGrafikId = document.getElementById("faturaGrafikIcerik");
        var odemelerId = document.getElementById("odemeIcerik");
        var kasaId = document.getElementById("kasaIcerik");

        faturaTabloId.style.display = "none";
        faturaGrafikId.style.display = "none";
        tahsilatId.style.display = "none";
        odemelerId.style.display = "block";
        kasaId.style.display = "none";
    }
    function getKasa() {
        var tahsilatId = document.getElementById("tahsilatlarIcerik");
        var faturaTabloId = document.getElementById("faturaTabloIcerik");
        var faturaGrafikId = document.getElementById("faturaGrafikIcerik");
        var odemelerId = document.getElementById("odemeIcerik");
        var kasaId = document.getElementById("kasaIcerik");

        faturaTabloId.style.display = "none";
        faturaGrafikId.style.display = "none";
        tahsilatId.style.display = "none";
        odemelerId.style.display = "none";
        kasaId.style.display = "block";
    }
```

AND I AM CALLING THESE FUNCTION IN a element WITH onclick event. Basically I am changing display propertie of selected tab to BLOCK and display properties of other tabs to NONE.
Now, I have 4 tab, but I can not imagine  what crowd of code will I need if it exceed to, for example 10 tabs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with CSS/javascript by changing the `z-indexes` of the pages (as divs) `onclick`. This would bring one in front of the other.

Just have a div containing all the tabs, and then divs with different ids for each one.

Start with the page divs all having `z-index:0;`, except for the home div, which has`z-index:1;`.

Each tab has an `onclick="nextpage('page1')` (Change page1 to the id of the corresponding page).

Then in the javascript, place this code:

```
function nextpage(pageid) {
    //Find the highest z-index. May need to be customized
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var highest_index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++) {
        if (parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex) > highest_index) {
        highest_index = parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex;
        }
    }
    var highest_index_1 = highest_index + 1;
    //set the z index of the tab-page to the highest+1
    getElementByid(pageid).object.style.zIndex="1";
}
```